# Join Filter and Average in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Due to cells limitation, I want to put the result of these two formulas in a cell

`=UNIQUE(FILTER($G$3:$G,$H$3:$H=N$2,$F$3:$F < $N$1,$F$3:$F>$O$1))` and
`= AVERAGE(FILTER($I$3:$I,$G$3:$G=N3,$H$3:$H=N$2, $F$3:$F < $N$1,$F$3:$F>$O$1 ))`

I used ampersand &, but it said circular dependency detected.

Please help

Comment: In which cell you are putting the formula?

Comment: I put the formula in N3.

Comment: You can't put formula to same cell where result will be displayed. That is the reason of circular reference. In `AVERAGE` formula you used `N3` so you can't get result in same cell.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to achieve specifically - do you also have a mock-up sheet available?

Comment: First I want to filter unique variables then I want to calculate the average of each variable, and put all (variables and its average) in a cell.

Comment: paste some sample data here and people can help:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13OZhqzd9aD76JZVDtdC1NFeDkXMW6tZot8HUkSuCH4U/edit

Comment: Here is some data. I want to calculate Course and Average with one formula in one cell.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13OZhqzd9aD76JZVDtdC1NFeDkXMW6tZot8HUkSuCH4U/edit#gid=2100307022

Comment: Why is CONCATENATE not acceptable to use?